# TypeError: get_id() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' in Flask

Tags: flask

im trying to create login function (without registration)on my own website and im getting this error:

TypeError: get_id() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

I've tried to google this, but i didn't find the working anwser.

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request,  url_for, flash, redirect
import os
from flask import send_from_directory
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_login import UserMixin, login_user, LoginManager, login_required,logout_user,current_user
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired,Length,ValidationError

choices=[('1', 'M'), ('2', "F")]

SECRET_KEY = os.urandom(32)
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = SECRET_KEY

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = "login"

@login_manager.user_loader
@app.route('/')

@app.route('/home')
def home():    
    return render_template('home.html')


class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    login_username = StringField(validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=20)],render_kw={"placeholder":"username"})
    password = PasswordField(validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=20)], render_kw={"placeholder":"password"})
    submit = SubmitField("Login")

class registrationForm(FlaskForm):
    login_username = StringField(validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=20)],render_kw={"placeholder":"username"})
    password = PasswordField(validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=20)], render_kw={"placeholder":"password"})


class User(FlaskForm, UserMixin):
    login_username = "12345"
    password = "12345"

@app.route('/login',  methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    print(form.validate_on_submit())
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        login_user(User)
        redirect('user_profile')
        #flash('Logged in successfully.')
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)

@app.route('/user_profile', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def user_profile():
    return render_template('user_profile.html')



@app.route('/favicon.ico')
def favicon():
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static'), 'favicon/favicon.ico',mimetype='image/vnd.microsoft.icon')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="192.168.1.124",port=80,debug=True)
```

Here is login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="static/favicon/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="static/favicon/site.webmanifest">
    <title>Login Page with Username and Password Example</title>
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static\style\style.css" />
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/FD126C42-EBFA-4E12-B309-BB3FDD723AC1/main.js?attr=GA84mroqLJ3kxRYkjcFaFrPZ23jD8e1QN0kMVKLqcSVp_du2wwu0l_8AQBYBmRK9IUJKE_ZBwKS0oHvqtiME9nl4nW3Xk9294TXik7puZ3VaJwMEy4-b9lw5IVCcm8O5"
      charset="UTF-8"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <body class="align">
      <div class="grid">
        <form action="#" method="POST" class="form login">
          <div class="form__field">
            <label for="login__username"
              ><svg class="icon">
                <use
                  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                  xlink:href="#user"
                ></use></svg
              ><span class="hidden">Username</span></label
            >
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            {{ form.login_username }}
          </div>
          <div class="form__field">
            <label for="login__password"
              ><svg class="icon">
                <use
                  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                  xlink:href="#lock"
                ></use></svg
              ><span class="hidden">Password</span></label
            >
            {{ form.password }}
          </div>
          <div class="form__field">
           {{ form.submit}}
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icons">
        <symbol id="arrow-right" viewBox="0 0 1792 1792">
          <path
            d="M1600 960q0 54-37 91l-651 651q-39 37-91 37-51 0-90-37l-75-75q-38-38-38-91t38-91l293-293H245q-52 0-84.5-37.5T128 1024V896q0-53 32.5-90.5T245 768h704L656 474q-38-36-38-90t38-90l75-75q38-38 90-38 53 0 91 38l651 651q37 35 37 90z"
          />
        </symbol>
        <symbol id="lock" viewBox="0 0 1792 1792">
          <path
            d="M640 768h512V576q0-106-75-181t-181-75-181 75-75 181v192zm832 96v576q0 40-28 68t-68 28H416q-40 0-68-28t-28-68V864q0-40 28-68t68-28h32V576q0-184 132-316t316-132 316 132 132 316v192h32q40 0 68 28t28 68z"
          />
        </symbol>
        <symbol id="user" viewBox="0 0 1792 1792">
          <path
            d="M1600 1405q0 120-73 189.5t-194 69.5H459q-121 0-194-69.5T192 1405q0-53 3.5-103.5t14-109T236 1084t43-97.5 62-81 85.5-53.5T538 832q9 0 42 21.5t74.5 48 108 48T896 971t133.5-21.5 108-48 74.5-48 42-21.5q61 0 111.5 20t85.5 53.5 62 81 43 97.5 26.5 108.5 14 109 3.5 103.5zm-320-893q0 159-112.5 271.5T896 896 624.5 783.5 512 512t112.5-271.5T896 128t271.5 112.5T1280 512z"
          />
        </symbol>
      </svg>
    </body>
  </body>
</html>
```

user_profile.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>User Profile</title>
</head>
<body>
    user profile
</body>
</html>
```

Can you tell me what im doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The `UserMixin` [class](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/082badd924a678445795721d67f8f6bf3f29ad58/src/flask_login/mixins.py) in the `Flask-Login` package has an `id` field. This `id` value is accessed with the `get_id()` method.

```
def get_id(self):
    try:
        return str(self.id)
    except AttributeError:
        raise NotImplementedError("No `id` attribute - override `get_id`") from None
```

Please define a unique id value for your `User` object that inherit the `UserMixin` class.